# When the aler coming like that i don't understand and alos couldn't find it with searching on google

Tags: security, command-line-arguments

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\Example\setup.exe" -s"

what does it mean -s command ? what does it do? It's command line of windows or windows server. I need to find what it can do. During the analysis of Alert I missed this one.